# How to get all deployed application in tomcat server

Tags: java, tomcat, monitoring

I am going to create an application for monitoring tomcat . Is there is any way to get all applications deployed in a tomcat ( any web service provided tomcat for getting that or is there is any other way to find it). 
For example: Input is `http://ip:port` which points to a tomcat server. i need to get the all applications deployed on corresponding url (tomcat). How its possible? But here my application installed on a different server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are able to use JMX, then that is the way !, [JMX](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/javamanagement-140525.html) is the integrated technology to Java standard edition that allows any application provide management and monitoring to its users , and of course Tomcat includes that.

you would do a query like

```
JMXQuery=Catalina:j2eeType=WebModule,*
```

[check this site](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/monitoring.html)

Answer (score 3):

You can read and parse `http://hostname:port/manager/html` page. It contains a list of deployed applications

Comment: Is it done through programmatically without parsing.